# how to unbind a mode hook without restarting

Tags: hooks

I had set up a custom hook for a mode, but I now realize that I want to use the mode without my changes and without my hook. So, I want the mode to behave as if I never set the hook in the first place, and I want to do this without restarting emacs. Is this reasonably doable?

For example, if I was using the following hook:

```
(add-hook 'my-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
           ;; Do a bunch of stuff...ie:
           (local-set-key (kbd "C-c l")
                          'some-fancy-function)
           )
)
```

I can achieve my goal by deleting the hook for `my-mode` from my `init.el`, restarting emacs, and then using `my-mode` as a default setup. But can I do this without restarting emacs?

Comment: It looks like my best bet is to use functions instead of lambda's, and then using the `remove-hook` command to remove the function from the hook, as outlined in the selected answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671045/function-that-remove-specific-lambda-from-a-hook-in-emacs

Comment: I am planning to post an answer when I have this figured out...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using function symbols certainly makes this easier (and this is one of the reasons why I would recommend always using that approach). You can still use `remove-hook` with the lambda form, though -- it just needs to be the *same* lambda form as the one you added!

```el
(remove-hook 'my-mode-hook
             (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'some-fancy-function)))
```

If you've edited the original code in the interim, you might find it simpler to inspect the `my-mode-hook` variable to figure out which value to remove.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it in [my config](https://github.com/abo-abo/oremacs/blob/github/oleh/hooks.el) by consistently naming all my hooks.  I use `eval-defun` on a hook function to re-define it, followed possibly by `revert-buffer` in relevant buffers. This approach also helps with autoloading mode-specific configuration:

```
hooks.el:
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'ora-c++-hook)

modes/ora-c++.el:
;;;###autoload
(defun ora-c++-hook ()
  (auto-complete-mode 1)
  (c-toggle-auto-newline)
  ;; (hs-minor-mode)
  )
```

Thanks to the consistent naming, it's possible to define a function that jumps to the hook that corresponds to the current mode - very useful.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem is to use defined functions instead of lambdas for my custom config code, and using `remove-hook` to undo the custom config.

For example, from my hook above, I would make the following changes:

```el
(defun my-mode-config ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'some-fancy-function))

(add-hook 'my-mode-hook 'my-mode-config)
```

which provides the same functionality as the above code. But with this new code, I can reset my mode as follows:

```el
(remove-hook 'my-mode-hook 'my-mode-config)
```

That's it!