# Hook with quoted lambda as an argument

Tags: hooks, functions, quote

I been reading a blog post from Chris Wanstrath from 2010 where he write about `coffee-mode`. He proposed there this functions hook:

```elisp
(defun coffee-custom ()
  "coffee-mode-hook"

  ;; Emacs key binding
  (define-key coffee-mode-map [(meta r)] 'coffee-compile-buffer))

(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook (lambda () (coffee-custom)))
```

In `coffee-mode.el` you can see similar hook call

```elisp
"... Add `(lambda () (coffee-cos-mode t))' to `coffee-mode-hook' to turn
it on by default."
```

I don't understand the use of lambda calling another function in order to execute it. Why not simply:

```elisp
(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook #'my:coffee-custom)
```

Resources: http://ozmm.org/posts/coffee_mode.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook '(lambda () (coffee-custom)))`

Definitely not recommended.

1. Quoting lambdas like that is [not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20948325/324105).
2. As you say, `(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook #'coffee-custom)` would be better (for [many](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18886/454) [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27264339/324105)).

> In coffee-mode.el you can see similar hook call
>
> ```
> "... Add `'(lambda () (coffee-cos-mode t))' to `coffee-mode-hook'
> ```

This one at least had a purpose, as it's passing an argument; however:

1. Again with the quoted lambda.
2. I'd still recommend using a named function instead of a lambda, even if you have to define it yourself.
3. If `coffee-cos-mode` is a minor mode defined with the standard macro then the argument will be [redundant in this scenario](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5364/454) (since Emacs 24.1), in which case you could just add `#'coffee-cos-mode` to the hook, in the same fashion as the previous scenario.

Comment: You mean it is no a good idea because that cause redundant function call or is there some other reason?

Comment: Having function code (possibly in byte-compiled form) in a hook variable is just messy.  Inspecting the variable becomes harder to understand; removing the function from the hook becomes harder; updating the function in the hook becomes harder.  With a named function symbol, all those things are nice and easy.

Comment: n.b. One of my links is ostensibly about key bindings, but relevant here due to the issue of the (possibly-compiled) function code being just as hard to read in a hook value as it is in `describe-key` output.

Comment: Yes, readability was my drive as well. Thank you!