# How to make all variables and functions of a mode visible without activating the mode

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode, load

Let's say I want to customize a keybind for a mode that hasn't been loaded yet like so:

`(define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "C-M-i") 'eshell-previous-input)`

But the problem is if I haven't yet loaded `eshell` I get this error:
`Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable eshell-mode-map)`

How would I make the keymap visible **without** opting for the mode-hook `eshell-mode-hook`?
Are there multiple ways of achieving this?
If so, what is the standard way of doing so (loading files to make variables/functions/keymaps visible)?

Also, what would the implications be if I decided to load the file manually as opposed to using a mode-hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't :)  At least, not for this use-case.

Instead you *defer* your configuration until such time as the library in question has been loaded:

```
(with-eval-after-load "esh-mode"
  (define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "C-M-i") 'eshell-previous-input))
```

Note that <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `eshell-mode-map` provided me with the "esh-mode" library name.

---

If you *did* want to "make all variables and functions of a mode visible without activating the mode" then you would `require` the library.  e.g.:

```
(require 'eshell)
```

---

> Also, what would the implications be if I decided to load the file manually as opposed to using a mode-hook?

If you load the file, then you incur the cost of doing so.  If that's happening at init time, then you've slowed down your start-up time slightly.  If it's possible that you won't even use `eshell` in a given session, then this probably isn't what you want to do.  (Or if you invariably run emacs as a server which starts when your system boots, then maybe you *do* want to pre-load things to make it that much more responsive later on, should you happen use that feature -- your call.)

If you use a mode hook then you are once again deferring the evaluation -- but rather than evaluating the code once, you are (re)evaluating it every time any buffer enters that mode.  In this particular use-case we only need it to happen once, so `with-eval-after-load` is more appropriate.

Comment: You gave what is generally the right answer (i.e., would be correct for most modes), but `eshell` does things the hard way. :) For some reason, `eshell` actually creates its keymap in the `eshell-mode` command and sets it with `setq-local`. (Search for `;; FIXME: What the hell!?` in `esh-mode.el`.) This means that to redefine `eshell-mode-map` keys you need to do it everytime the mode is activated, in `eshell-mode-hook`, for example.

Answer (score 5):

@phils gave you what is almost always the correct answer, that is, it
is the right answer for most major and minor modes; but in the
case of `eshell` you need to do something else:

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "C-M-i") 'eshell-previous-input)))
```

The reason is that, unlike most modes, `eshell` creates its keymap
very late, in fact, it does it every time you activate the mode. In
the file `esh-mode.el`, inside the `(define-derived-mode eshell-mode
...)` definition, you'll find:

```
;; FIXME: What the hell!?
(setq-local eshell-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(use-local-map eshell-mode-map)
```

Comment: That's certainly unusual.  It goes to show that there are always special cases!  Good answer.  I would just recommend using a named function instead of a lambda for the hook, to make it easier to [modify](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18886/454) and [inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27264339/324105).